# iPhone App: Camera is not working properly in portrait mode but works in landscape

Tags: unity-game-engine, landscape-portrait, xcode9.2, ios11.2

I am developing an iPhone application using Unity 5.6.4p2 and Vuforia. After build from Unity, opened in xCode 9.2, building and installed it to iPhone 6s/ipad pro (ios11.2). When I open the application in my iPhone/iPad in portrait mode the camera is not opening normally, sometime camera take 10/20 Sec for open or the App become hang for 30/40 Sec and sometime it become permanently hang until forced close the App. But in landscape mode the camera open normally and App works fine.

How to solve this?

The App build from Unity for android works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Okey, got the solution. Before build for Xcode from Unity, uncheck the "Auto Graphics API" from Player Settings > Other Settings. And in Optimization "Script Call Optimization" should Fast but no Exception.